# How to specify the element in flexbox to wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I am learning using Flexbox to do layout, right now, suppose I have 10 divs inside a flexbox container, how can I make it wrap at the 7th div to next line and keep the 2nd div take rest remaining available space?

Like this(when screen width smaller than 800px ):

```
|1|    2    |3|4|5|6|
|  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 |
```

And `|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|` when larger than 800px

Comment: I'd rather see what you have rather than imagine it.

Comment: @Daedalus Hi, do you just mean a DEMO?

Comment: A demonstration would work, sure.

Comment: I meant your html/css.

Comment: @Daedalus If I can do that, then I do not need to ask this question

Comment: A demo of what you have is, whether you believe it or not, relevant.  To offer a little explanation; if those offering you a solution do not know what you've tried already, they're likely going to tell you what  you've already tried, and more time is spent trying to figure out what you haven't given us.

Comment: @Daedalus I have not figured out any of this part, so basically anyone can help me from the ground

Comment: Are you saying, that you've typed exactly zero characters of code?

Comment: @Daedalus Yes, however I tried some but not work at all

Comment: In case it is not obvious at this point in time.. . I'm asking you to post _what you've tried_.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks, I guess I will just turn to others to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify which exact element in to wrap with flexbox. You can however use `flex-basis: xx%;` and some trial'n'error to make it wrap like you want.

Here's a working sample with 10 boxes on line at 800px+ width, and it wraps after the seventh element, because of `flex-basis: 12%;` with the rest of the three boxes filling remaining space. 
Please note however, that when you shrink the screen even further, the wrapping will change to after 6th element (due to the percentage nature), so you will need an extra media query around that state.

[Working example on Codepen.](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/pvXVBg?editors=110)

Flexbox, as the name says, is flexible - And it's not really meant to be restrained - But for now there's no better way to make have this behaviour.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 12%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;

  background-color: red;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .box {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Remember your vendor-prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for help. I guess that is it, I eventually end using JS to manually position those divs. But your answer helps.

Comment: Cool that you found a solution that works for you. If you feel my suggestion answered your question and helped you further, please close this question by accepting the answer.

Comment: You close it by clicking the checkmark just below the up-down votes on my answer :)